# How to get an image above a border

Tags: css, image

Here is what I want : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWzZd.png)

To get the bar, I'm using a border-left, and to get the bullet an image. 
However, the bullet image is behind the bar.

How could I get the bullet image above the border-left ?

```
`<div id="verticalbar">
`...<p class = "g"><img id="bullet" src="bullet.png"/><b>Somethinghere</b></p> ...</div`>
```

I tried something with z-index but it does not work.

Comment: We need to see an example of your code to be able to help

Comment: Why don't you add the border to the image itself?

Comment: Set the image to absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative position for the element that has the border and absolute positions with according position settings for the images. The image has to be a direct child of the element with the border for this code to work properly:

```
p.g {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solidblack;
}
p.g. > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 24px; 
}
```

(values as needed, use IDs or classes to address different images)

Comment: Is the image not a direct child element of `p.g`?  Then erase the `>` in the second rule

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [border-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) ?

```
border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWzZd.png) 30 stretch;
border-right: none; // Reset the border-right
```

```css
#borderimg { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWzZd.png) 30 stretch;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="borderimg">text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the bullet must be align with "text".

Answer (score 0):

You can set position:relative to the parent and to the bullets and then you can use left/right negative positioning. For example

```
p.g{
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}
p.g img{
    position:relative;
    left:-4px;/*the exact pixels you need*/
}
```